# Get a parameter's name

Tags: reflection, plsql

I want to get a parameter's name in plsql.

For example,

```
procedure sp_example(myParam in varchar2) is

paramName varchar2(30);
begin
    paramName = 'myParam';
end
end procedure sp_example;
```

Is there a way to get the name of `myParam` using reflection, instead of hard coding it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
select argument_name from all_arguments where object_name = 'SP_EXAMPLE';
```

This view can also show you the data types, positions, etc., and you can use it in SQL or PL/SQL.  Plenty of info in the various metadata views.

Comment: You can use `OWA_UTIL.who_called_me` and a `who_am_i` procedure to dynamically get the procedure owner and name.  But unfortunately there's no easy way to get the name of the procedure within a package.  http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2009/10/httpasktomoraclecomtkytewhocalledme.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the names of  parameters retrieved in their respective positions, use

`select argument_name from user_arguments where object_name='SAMPLE_PROC' order by position;`