# oracle plsql: retrieve runtime parameter values when you call a procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, parameters, plsql, oracle10g

I need a generalized method to get list of runtime parameters (values) when I call a procedure. I need something similar to the $$PLSQL_UNIT that returns the name of the running procedure.
(plsql Oracle 10g)

E.g. look at this sample procedure:
(it simply prints its own name and parameters )

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE  MY_PROC(ow in varchar2, tn IN varchar2)
 IS

BEGIN
     dbms_output.put_line('proc_name: '||$$PLSQL_UNIT||' parameters: '|| ow||' '||tn  );

    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERRORE: ' ||SQLERRM);

END MY_PROC;
/
```

Running procedure produces the following output:

```
SQL> 
  1   BEGIN
  2     IBAD_OWN.MY_PROC('first_par', 'second_par');
  3   END;
  4  /

proc_name: MY_PROC parameters: first_par second_par

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

I'm not satisfy because I can't copy and paste in all my procedures because I have to hard code each procedure to set their right parameter variables.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160928/get-a-parameters-name/ ?

Comment: yes, i think it's the same question. Both without answer :( I think there isn't a way to get value of parameters :(

Comment: I don't think it is the same question. You're asking for the _value_ of a parameter without knowing it's name. As pointed out in a, now deleted, answer and in the linked question finding the name of a parameter is easy but not the value of that parameter.

Comment: @LucaVaccaro not sure I understand exactly.  The "value of the parameters" is found simply by inspecting the parameter variable itself, as you did in your MY_PROC example above ("ow" and "tn" contain the parameter values).  Can you be more clear what you want to do?  Tks

Comment: @tbone yes i did it but it works only for MY_PROC. Think at MY_PROC2 MY_PROC3, MY_PROC4 where any procedure has its own parameter (eg. MY_PROC2 (IN owner, IN table); MY_PROC3 (IN index, IN ow, IN table); MY_PROC4 (IN idx, IN own, IN t, IN part). How you can see, I have to write my trace into each procedure, paying attention to the exactly parameters name. I can't do copy&paste. That's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible to dynamically retrieve the values of parameters passed to a procedure in Oracle PL/SQL. The language simply isn't designed to handle this kind of operation.

Incidentally, in a procedure that is located within a package, `$$PLSQL_UNIT` will only return the package's name. I find it's better to define a consistently-named constant within each procedure that contains the procedure's name.

Answer (score 1):

When I wanted the same functionality as yours I didn't find any good built-in solution.

What I did is: wrote DB-level trigger which modifies original body of function/procedure/package.
This trigger adds immediatly after "begin" dynamically generated piece of code from "user_arguments".

Plus, after that I include into this trigger the code, that logs calls of procs when exception occures.

Plus, you can trace procs calls, and many more interisting things.

But this solution works fine only for preproduction because performance decreases dramatically.

PS. Sorry for my bad English.